# Label or score outliers in R

Tags: r, outliers

I'm looking for some easy to use algorithms in R to label (outlier or not) or score (say, 7.5) outliers row-wise. Meaning, I have a matrix `m` that contains several rows and I want to identify rows who represent outliers compared to the other rows.

```
m <- matrix( data = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1), ncol = 3 )
```

To illustrate some more, I want to compare all the (complete) rows in the matrix with each other to spot outliers.

Comment: This is very broad. Can you narrow it down? Give an example?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and then update your question to conform to these guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some really simple outlier detection (using either the boxplot statistics or quantiles of the data) that I wrote a few years ago.

[Outliers](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/resume_ex_code/blob/master/outliers.R)

But, as noted, it would be helpful if you'd describe your problem with greater precision.

#### Edit:

Also you say you want **row-wise** outliers. Do you mean to say that you're interested in identifying whole rows vs observations within a variable (as is typically done)? If so, you'll want to use some sort of distance metric, though which metric you choose will depend on your data.

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I have added some information to my original question. I'm not entirely sure I understand your understanding of row-wise outliers. As stated above, I want to compare all the information (meaning, all the cells in a given row) in a given row to all the other rows in the matrix.

Comment: So, (a) your matrix `m` is very unhelpful; (b) your definition of "row outliers" is not an outlier in the traditional sense. It's sensing observations that have large distances between them in p-dim space, eg `dist(m)`

Comment: Thank you, Alex! This is exactly what I was looking for! But how do I read the dist-table? BTW: The matrix I provided is very close to what I actually have.